# BeautifulSoup - Select String Based on Dictionary Key

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape an HTML page and looking to select a string based on an array key not an element tag.

In this case I am looking to use "fmt_headline" as the key to grab "Founder and CEO at SolarThermoChemical LLC".

```
<div id="srp_main_" class="">
<code id="voltron_srp_main-content" style="display:none;">

"fmt_headline":"Founder and CEO at SolarThermoChemical LLC",
"isConnectedEnabled":true,
"sharedConnectionToken":"240506fce660"

</div>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Not without any idea of the HTML you're trying to parse -- that code block you showed ain't HTML, and HTML is what BS parses!-)

Comment: I'm pulling it from this page (just updated the block with tags): view-source:https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords=John+Mankins&orig=GLHD&rsid=373993061422766130017&pageKey=voltron_federated_search_internal_jsp&trkInfo=&search=Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've parsed your HTML with BeautifulSoup, it can give you all the text:

```
2>>> x
'<div id="srp_main_" class="">\n<code id="voltron_srp_main-content" style="display:none;">\n\n"fmt_headline":"Founder and CEO at SolarThermoChemical LLC",\n"isConnectedEnabled":true,\n"sharedConnectionToken":"240506fce660"\n\n</div>'
2>>> soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(x)
2>>> y=soup.get_text()
2>>> y
u'\n\n\n"fmt_headline":"Founder and CEO at SolarThermoChemical LLC",\n"isConnectedEnabled":true,\n"sharedConnectionToken":"240506fce660"\n\n'
```

Now, further analysis of that text is left to other tools, such as regular expressions:

```
2>>> import re
2>>> mo = re.search(r'"fmt_headline":"([^"]*)"', y)
2>>> print(mo.group(1))
Founder and CEO at SolarThermoChemical LLC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired data is in the comment section of the html. So you need to extract the comment first.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

tag = soup.find('code', attrs={'id': "voltron_srp_main-content"})
tag_comments = tag.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

Now, form `tag_comments` you can parse it as json (it looks like json) or use regex as shown in Alex Martelli's answer.